# Multiple rows update - update column NULL if blank field

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that updates multiple row ids with 6 fields, I am trying to get the correct code to set the column to NULL if there is nothing changed.
Below is my code.
What I am trying to do is at the (shippedto_customer), the update works fine if I dont add in the if statement, but I want the if statement in case user does not change the date for the field shippedto_customer.
Sorry if I am not explaining correctly.

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    $count=count($_POST["id"]);

    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        $sql1="UPDATE $tbl_name SET status='" . $_POST['status'][$i] . "', 
ship_from_factory='" . $_POST['ship_from_factory'][$i] . "', 
shippedto_customer=if(shippedto_customer='',NULL,'" . 
            $_POST['shippedto_customer'][$i] . "'), ship_comments='" . 
            $_POST['ship_comments'][$i] . "' WHERE id='" . $_POST['id'][$i] . "'";
        $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
    }
}
```

Comment: For a start you should use PHP Prepared Statements and ***STOP*** using `mysql_` PHP functions. [**HERE** is a good place to start learning how to do this](https://phptherightway.com/)

Comment: Why are you using an archaic and insecure API that was deprecated almost a decade ago?

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface which was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Here parameters are **NOT** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and this has severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Escape **any** and all user data, especially from `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're testing the old `shippedto_customer` in the table, not the value from the form.

You can use the `NULLIF()` function to test if the value being stored is an empty string, and store `NULL` instead.

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    $count=count($_POST["id"]);

    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        $status = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['status'][$i]);
        $ship_from_factory = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ship_from_factory'][$i]);
        $shipped_to_customer = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['shippedto_customer'][$i]);
        }
        $ship_comments = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ship_comments'][$i]);
        $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'][$i]);
        $sql1="UPDATE $tbl_name
               SET status='$staus', ship_from_factory='$ship_from_factory', 
                   shippedto_customer=NULLIF('$shipped_to_customer', ''), 
                   ship_comments='$ship_comments' WHERE id='$id'";
        $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
    }
}
```

If you're forced to use the old `mysql` extension, you need to escape all the parameters. I've shown that above. But as mentioned in the comments, you should migrate to a modern MySQL API (I recomment PDO) and use prepared statements. If you do this, a PHP `null` value will be converted automatically to SQL `NULL` when used as a parameter.